# Criteria Query unable to fetch Data

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I've a hbm file for my database view with all the columns as composite key

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false">
    <class name="com.sample.dataobject.MyView"
        table="MY_VIEW" >
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="code" type="string">
                <column name="CODE" length="2" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="Id" type="string">
                <column name="ID" length="14" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="Desc" type="string">
                <column name="DESC" length="256" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="TypeCode" type="string">
                <column name="TYPE_CODE" length="2" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In the above view, the column `DESC` can be a null value.

I've written a criteria query to fetch results based on `CODE` and `ID`

```
Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(MyView.class);
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("code", 'US'));
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("Id", '12'));
    List<MyView> annuityServices= c.list();
```

There are 2 rows in the View which satisfies these conditions, but the List which is returned is `[null,null]`

Also when i put a logger to check the query and value, it returns 2 rows but break at DESC column which is `null`

```
    2017-06-07 17:08:19 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([CODE_1_390_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [US]
2017-06-07 17:08:19 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([ID_2_390_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [12]
2017-06-07 17:08:19 TRACE BasicExtractor:68 - extracted value ([DESC_9_390_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null]
2017-06-07 17:08:19 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([CODE_1_390_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [US]
2017-06-07 17:08:19 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([ID_2_390_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [12]
2017-06-07 17:08:19 TRACE BasicExtractor:68 - extracted value ([DESC_9_390_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [null]
```

Is there something wrong, or criteria API breaks when a `null` value is encountered?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the above view, the column DESC can be a null value.

According to [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers), primary key have to be **not null**:

> The values cannot be null. For composite ids, no part can be null.